# Is the savefile from the regular Skyrim the same of the GOTY Edition?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I'm actually playing the regular TES: Skyrim on my Ps3, but i want to know if i could keep my save data if i buy the GOTY, more complete version.

Edit: I already saw in other websites that the save files are actually compatible, but i wanted to be sure on a more serious site like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, saves are forward compatible from the regular edition to legendary edition. Note, however, according to [the official support page](http://help.bethsoft.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18441/kw/save) you may have issues going in reverse (from legendary to regular).

Comment: Indeed. In fact, the biggest issue with this sort of thing is mostly the addition of the new content.

Worst case scenario, if anybody is attempting to do this in reverse, the less you have done in regards to the DLC content not found on the original disc, the easier the save should run. Given DLC is mostly account bound on console, I am doubtful there would be an issue of saves not loading, just saves loading without particular weapons, statistics, shouts etc.

Comment: @Timelord64 There are additional changes that took places beyond just DLC for this particular release, and that can sometimes involve a different format or additional info in the save which can cause issues. It may be just playing the DLC causes the issues, but the support page doesn't clarify (for good reason, I'd imagine) and instead just said you should consider saves more one-way.

Answer (score 1):

With a game like The Elder Scrolls: Skyrim, the legendary edition is just a copy of the original game, with all of the DLC. A good way to check this out in the future is to look at the [achievements](http://www.trueachievements.com/searchresults.aspx?search=skyrim) page ([trophies](http://www.truetrophies.com/searchresults.aspx?search=skyrim) for PlayStation).

If the legendary edition has a different achievement page (may even be the same achievements, just a different entry), save transfer is questioned as they are not the exact same game.

For games where you are just getting DLC content with the new version, you are almost always playing the same game in terms of your save content. Games like Diablo 3:Reaper of Souls are entirely separate games (often due to extensive game change) and do not naturally exchange save data - however, developers may put work arounds in, such as the "character export" feature of Diablo 3.